# API to get Crystal RPT version

Tags: crystal-reports

In the Crystal Studio, I can get to the version of an rpt file by going to Report|Performance Information|Report Definition|File Format Schema.

Is there a way of getting to this same information via the Crystal .NET API?

I can't find it for the life of me.

OLIVER

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out `ReportDocument.ReportClientDocument.MajorVersion` and `MinorVersion`. You'll need to add a reference to `CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc` to access it.

```
using(var rptDoc = new ReportDocument()) 
{
    rptDoc.Load(path);
    Console.WriteLine(rptDoc.ReportClientDocument.MajorVersion);
}
```